# An error prevents replication from synchronizing : String or binary data would be truncated. [SQLSTATE 22001] (Error 8152)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I've gotten this error message in Job History of merge replication job :

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. String or binary data would be
>   truncated. [SQLSTATE 22001] (Error 8152).  The step failed.

I know what the message meant but no idea what did cause that because the database model is the same !

Any suggestions of what can cause this particular error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours working with the Profiler I found that a very long stored procedure caused the issue.
 When added to updates to subscribers. The column that holds the Alter procedure is a 4000 character long but the stored procedure was much bigger "Cause of embedded documentation". Same problem raised [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/b7e91680-f317-4eca-b685-cfdf44ef2097/)